# Keep text on an image readable while rotating the image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, uilabel

I have an image view that looks like a wheel. This view detects touch events on each of the colored sections.

The problem I have is that when I rotate this wheel, the `UILabel`s on top of the view need to also be rotated so that the text is still horizontal and human readable.

What is the best way to rotate the labels while the parent view is being rotated?

[image]

This is what I am trying now and it does not rotate correctly...

```
CGAffineTransform textTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, newAngle * -1);
```

Comment: Have you tried making an aggregate view where the labels are subviews of the graphical wheel view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are applying a rotation transform to rotate the wheel. If the labels are subviews of the wheel view, their centers are pinned in the right places to the wheel (because a view is located in its superview by its center), and they will travel around with it. At the same time, apply the inverse rotation transform to the labels. The rotation takes place around the center of each label. So each label stays in the right place and stays upright.

An afterthought - also make sure you're not using autolayout on these labels. Autolayout breaks view transforms.

Comment: Thanks but i did try that... i will add code to show you what i have now. Is this the wrong way to set the text transform?

Comment: Yes. Look at your own code and think about it. Suppose the new transform is 30 degrees. Now you are taking a 30 degree rotate transform and rotating it 30 degrees the other way. That is a zero degree transform. So you are doing nothing at all to the labels, and they are rotating along with the wheel - just what you don't want. Do what I suggested - derive the inverse transform from the transform you applied to the wheel, and apply it to each label.

Comment: Thanks matt - this did end up working. My code to invert the angle was correct since it is in radians, not degrees. What i was doing wrong was initializing the next textTransform using the parent.transform instead of the label.transform by mistake...